# How to create an object like JavaScript in dart flutter and how to access statedata

Tags: flutter, dart

```html
  var statedata = {
     "name":"sajib",
     "name2":"sajib saha",
  };
```

i am create and object like javascript in dart file in flutter . but i can not get access of it ? how can i get call name or name2 to get the value . in javascript i can get statedata.name but its not working here please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type you're looking at is called a `Map`. To access a key, you specify the key name within brackets. For example:

```dart
var statedata = {
     "name":"sajib",
     "name2":"sajib saha",
  };
  print(statedata["name2"]);
```

Prints:

```
sajib saha
```

Comment: Text(
              statedate['_counter'],
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),

Comment: this give an error in text field flutter how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make abstract class. For example:

```
abstract class Statedata

{
 static String name = "sajib";

 static  String name2 = "sajib saha";

}
```

Now you can get access like in JS:

```
Statedata.name //"sajib"`
```